# VHDL syntax issue

Tags: vhdl

I'm getting an error during CheckSyntax for the following code I've tried. The error says:

```
"Line 48. parse error, unexpected VARIABLE Line 53. Undefined symbol 'InOutDetector'.
 Line 57. InOutDetector: Undefined symbol (last report in this block)".
```

Can you let me know how should I fix this?

Here is an image of my code, as I could not paste it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ay8pjq4ojoep6ry/RoomLightController.png?dl=0

```
entity Room_Light_Controller is
port (
        clk, sA, sB: IN STD_LOGIC;
                    sL:     OUT STD_LOGIC
    );
end Room_Light_Controller;

architecture Behavioral of Room_Light_Controller is
  -- assuming sensors are variables sA and sB, and lights switch is sL
 SIGNAL People                                    : INTEGER:=0;
 SIGNAL AllowNextCount                    : BIT:='0';

    --unsigned int People=0;                      -- counter for people inside the room
    --char AllowNextCount=0;              -- boolean indicating if allowing next count or not
    --short int InOutDetector;        -- 1 = entering; -1 = exiting
begin
    variable InOutDetectorDetector:   integer;
         process (clk)
                 begin
         if ((sA = '0') and (sB = '1')) then
             -- entering
             InOutDetector := 1;
         end if;
         if ((sA = '1') and (sb = '0')) then
             -- exiting
             InOutDetector := -1;
                     end if;
         if ((sA ='1') and (sB = '1') and (AllowNextCount = '1')) then
             -- only when both sensors are touched validate the people counter
             People := People+InOutDetector;
             -- count once then block counting until the same person has finished entering/exiting
             AllowNextCount <= '0';
         end if;
         if ((sA = '0') and (sB = '0')) then
             -- it gets 0;0 only when someone has finished entering/exiting
             -- pr at turn on; so now allow to counting again
             AllowNextCount <= '1';
                   end if;
         if (People > 0) then
                                      sL <= '1'; -- Turn/keep lights on as long as People greater than 0
         else
                                      sL <= '0'; -- otherwise, turn them off
         end if;
         end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The declaration doesn't match the use. Fix that...

Comment: Your question isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), The line numbers don't match what are presented in your PNG image, nor will most potential answer be willing to OCR the image.  Your line numbers in error messages don't match your image.

Comment: Notice you're also missing the context clause.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable inside the process and rename it to (InOutDetector). You used (InOutDetector) inside the process.

Then if you want to run the process on clk rising edge, complete your process such as the following code :

```
process(clk)
   variable InOutDetector : integer;
begin
   if clk = '1' and clk'event then
      -- your code
   end if;
end process;
```

However if you don't want to use the clk rising edge, just complete the sensitivity list with parameters that you read or check it inside the process (sA,sB,AllowNextCount,People) and remove clk from the process sensitivity list.

Also be careful about incomplete if statements. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements.

Comment: You missed the other error in the code. `People:=People+InOutDetector;` should be `People <= People + InOutDetector;`.  People is a signal.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the error Amir notes that there is a name mismatch and the variable is declared in the wrong place, there is an additional error with the assignment to `People`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Room_Light_Controller is
    port (
        clk, sA, sB:    in std_logic;
        sL:             out std_logic
    );
end entity Room_Light_Controller;

architecture Behavioral of Room_Light_Controller is
  -- assuming sensors are variables sA and sB, and lights switch is sL
    signal people:          integer :=  0;
    signal allownextcount:  bit     := '0';

    --unsigned int People=0;              -- counter for people inside the room
    --char AllowNextCount=0;              -- boolean indicating if allowing next count or not
    --short int InOutDetector;            -- 1 = entering; -1 = exiting
begin
    -- variable InOutDetectorDetector:   integer;
    process (clk)
        variable InOutDetector:   integer; -- as per Amir
    begin
        if sA = '0' and sB = '1' then
            -- entering
            InOutDetector := 1;
        end if;
        if sA = '1' and sb = '0' then
            -- exiting
            InOutDetector := -1;
        end if;
        if sA ='1' and sB = '1' and AllowNextCount = '1' then
            -- only when both sensors are touched validate the people counter
            People <= People + InOutDetector;  -- was :=, signal assignment
            -- count once then block counting until the same person has finished entering/exiting
            AllowNextCount <= '0';
        end if;
        if sA = '0' and sB = '0' then
            -- it gets 0;0 only when someone has finished entering/exiting
            -- pr at turn on; so now allow to counting again
            AllowNextCount <= '1';
        end if;
        if People > 0 then
            sL <= '1'; -- Turn/keep lights on as long as People greater than 0
        else
            sL <= '0'; -- otherwise, turn them off
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture Behavioral;
```

`People` is a signal and requires the signal assignment symbol (`<=`) not the variable assignment symbol (`:=`).

After the two changes the VHDL design specification analyzes and elaborates.

Notice a context clause has been added to make your code a Minimal, Verifiable and Complete example.

Also note in the Help Center web page on [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the section **Minimal *and* readable**,

> ..Use consistent naming and indentation, and include comments if needed to explain portions of the code.

If this code were intended to be synthesize you might likely need to constrain the integers.

For execution efficiency all the independent if statements could be consolidated using elsif.  That's hardly an issue in a small design, but the binary patterns described for `sA` and `sB` are mutually exclusive (while not exhaustive for type std_logic).

You neglected to provide the complete error messages, which appear to be output from XST.  Historically the recommended design flow includes simulation, which if for no other purpose provides better syntax error messages from VHDL analysis.

XST historically assumes you are handing it a design description that is syntax error free, and is other wise quite sparse in providing adequate error messages.

The error message prefix (e.g. ERROR:HDLParsers:1209) can tell you how to find the problem via Xilinx's support site and/or documentation.

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution and help.Best regards!